# Ncurses: Read integers from user and store as variable

Tags: c, ncurses, conways-game-of-life

I am trying to implement the Game of Life using C/ncurses. One function I want my game to have is to take X, Y coordinates from the user and draw a shape on the board at these coordinates. I have a function that draws the shapes on the board and works fine. The header for that function is:

`void draw_shape(int x, int y, int shape[3][3])`

The keypress to draw a shape is handled in the title state of my game. The draw shape function works to draw any of the shapes. My only issue is getting the X, Y values from the user.

Title state of my game: 
    case TITLE:
            test = 0;
            int i, j;

```
        for(i = 0; i < (WELL_WIDTH-1); i++)
            for(j = 0; j < (WELL_HEIGHT-1); j++)
                cells[i][j] = create_cell(x_offset + i, y_offset + j);


        w = init_well(x_offset - 1, y_offset - 1, well_w, well_h);
        draw_well(w);
        mvprintw(y_offset + 5, x_offset + 10, "Welcome to the Game of Life!");
        mvprintw(y_offset + 7, x_offset + 9, "Press 'S' to start a new game.");
        mvprintw(y_offset + 8, x_offset + 9, "Press 'L' to load a saved game.");
        mvprintw(y_offset + 12, x_offset + 20, "-OR-");
        mvprintw(y_offset + 16, x_offset + 8, "Pick a shape to draw on the screen:");
        mvprintw(y_offset + 18, x_offset + 9, "(A) Still life   (B) Glider"); 
        mvprintw(y_offset + 19, x_offset + 9, "(C) Oscillator   (D) Random");


        keystrokes = read_keys();
        if (keystrokes == START_SAVE) {
            state = INIT; }
        if (keystrokes == LOADBOARD) {
            state = LOADGAME;
        }
        if (keystrokes == STILL_LIFE) {
            state = STILLIFE;

        }
```

When 'A' is pressed, state switches to STILLLIFE. This is where I want to get the X, Y values from the user and pass them to the drawshape function.

```
case STILLLIFE:

        w = init_well(x_offset - 1, y_offset - 1, well_w, well_h);
        draw_well(w);
        echo();

        int x_cord, y_cord;

        mvprintw(y_offset + 21, x_offset + 7, "Enter X, Y coordinates     for your shape: ");
```

Ideally, I would do something like:
 `scanw("%d, %d", &x_cord, &y_cord);`
and then
`draw_shape(x_cord, y_cord, shape);`
But when I tried this, it did not seem to work. I would try to display the values of x_cord and y_cord like this:
`mvprintw(y_offset + 23, x_offset + 7, "%d, %d", x_cord, y_cord);`
But, when I opened my game, there would already be bogus integer values for x_cord and y_cord before I had typed anything. I have tried many different methods, I'm really just looking for something equivalent to scanf. Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The example isn't complete enough to guess what the problem is (see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: Only your last paragraph is pertinent, and you don't provide the code with scanf which is failing you.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't solved this one yet, you need to `fflush` the line or hand EOF data or a number of ways `scanf`(or it's `scanw` equiv) can fail. [scanf kinda sucks honestly.](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html) `sscanf` and `fscanf` are alright, but there's just a lot of gotchas with `scanf`. The common advice is to use `fread` the whole string and then parse it with `sscanf`. Or if you just need single-letter inputs, think about using `getch` or `wgetch`.